# Magento Catalog Price Rule Suddenly Stops Working & Price Rule Not Applied on Custom Options

Tags: php, magento

I have been trying to solve the two problems the whole day but found no way to solve. Here are the 2 problems:

1. Catalog Price Rule suddenly stopped working (It has been working in the past few months). I have set the price rule, it is active and I have clicked 'Apply Rules'. But the price rule is not applied on any product and showing original prices only.
2. Catalog Price Rule is not applied on Custom Options' Price. (e.g. a product costs $300, a custom option costs extra $50, a 10% off price rule. The reasonable way should be (300+50)*0.9 = $315 but in magento it is 300*0.9+50 = $320).

Earlier today when the price rule was still working, I was trying to fix the second problem. I changed some code and all of a sudden the discounted price was gone (price rule suddenly stopped working). I instantly reverted my code changes but the discounted price is like gone forever... I have tried to recover all the changed code files to the original magento package but still no luck... So I guess it was not because of my modification to the code?

Any suggestion will be very much appreciated as I have been working on it the whole day.. but the situation turned out to be even worse so I am really frustrated...

Comment: I looked into the database. The table catalogrule_affected_product is empty while the other catalogrule_xxx tables are not. My price rule should apply to all the products. So probably this is the problem? I have tried to delete and recreate the table, delete the price rule and recreate one but still not working (the table is still empty). Any idea please? x.x

Answer (score 0):

The catalog price rule suddenly works again.. I have no idea why and the catalogrule_affected_product in the db is still empty...

Besides, I have figured out a workaround for problem 2. We cannot use fixed price custom options as price rule is applied before the extra price for custom option. But we can use percent priced custom option because price*custom_option_percent*price_rule_percent = price*price_rule_percent*custom_option_percent.

However, there is a bug with percent priced custom option. The Old Price shown is incorrect. It should be the product original price + custom option original price but turns out it is produst original price + custom option discounted price by default..

Here is the solution:

You have to modify 2 files. First one is `public function getPrice($flag=false)` in

> app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Option.php

Change it to

```
public function getPrice($flag=false)
    {

        /* original
        if ($flag && $this->getPriceType() == 'percent') {
            $basePrice = $this->getOption()->getProduct()->getFinalPrice();
            $price = $basePrice*($this->_getData('price')/100);
            return $price;
        }
        return $this->_getData('price');
        */


        if ($flag && $this->getPriceType() == 'percent') {
            $basePrice = $this->getProduct()->getFinalPrice();
            $price = $basePrice * ($this->_getData('price')/100);
            return $price;
        }

        if (!$flag && $this->getPriceType() == 'percent') {
            $basePrice = $this->getProduct()->getPrice();
            $price = $basePrice * ($this->_getData('price')/100);
            return $price;
        }

        return $this->_getData('price');
    }
```

According to `public function getJsonConfig()` in `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/View/Options.php`, $flag=true represents New Price and $flag=false represents Old Price. However, in the original code, $flag=false is not handled so we have to add it.

Second, we have to modify the javascript for price reloading. The js file is `js/varien/product.js`. Modify the function `reload: function()` (at around line 637).

This piece of code adds the extra custom option price to the final price. However, it adds the same amount to both Old and New price. So we have to add some code to handle the Old Price.

```
                // Add This
                var oldpriceflag = false;
                if (pair.value == 'old-price-'+this.productId) oldpriceflag = true;
                //


                var subPrice = 0;
                var subPriceincludeTax = 0;
                Object.values(this.customPrices).each(function(el){
                    if (el.excludeTax && el.includeTax) {
                        subPrice += parseFloat(el.excludeTax);
                        subPriceincludeTax += parseFloat(el.includeTax);

                    // Add This
                if (oldpriceflag) {
                            subPrice += parseFloat(el.oldPrice) - parseFloat(el.price);
                            subPriceincludeTax += parseFloat(el.oldPrice) - parseFloat(el.price);
                        }
                    //

                    } else {

                        // Remove This
                        //subPrice += parseFloat(el.price);
                        //subPriceincludeTax += parseFloat(el.price);
                        //

                        // Add This
                        if (oldpriceflag && typeof el.oldPrice != 'undefined') {
                        subPrice += parseFloat(el.oldPrice);
                            subPriceincludeTax += parseFloat(el.oldPrice);
                        }
                        else {
                            subPrice += parseFloat(el.price);
                            subPriceincludeTax += parseFloat(el.price);
                        }
                        //

                    }
                });
                excl += subPrice;
                incl += subPriceincludeTax;
```

I have spent so much time to solve this. Hope this helps someone from spending time on fixing this bug. ;-)